# Interchanging battery with a higher capacity battery

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

My Redmi 1s has a battery capacity 2050mAh (BM41). And the upgrade of the phone is Redmi 2 with capacity 2200mAh(BM44).

Can I use this battery if it fits in my device? Will it creates any software problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not Recommended in general**

- Battery Charging has [various stages](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)

[image]

- These stages are regulated and controlled by the the charging circuit in charger/ in device by firmware files to switch to various stages. Battery capacity is very much integral to this. By replacing with a battery of higher capacity (or extended battery unless OEM approved) charging may less than optimal and therefore the performance or life of battery could be affected
- **Edit:** The number of terminals and purpose could also vary ( some batteries have three terminals and some have 4). This would be an issue
- **Your case:** There is hardly a difference in mAh so it may not matter at all , if it fits- normally OEMs like Samsung make sure that the batteries cannot be interchanged between devices - can't say about Redmi. The benefit you would get is marginal, so would recommend playing safe and **not** replacing to avoid **any problems**

Comment: And also, it's very important to make sure the voltage level matches. Overvolting the CPU is dangerous, whereas undervolting decreases performance. Mention about that too :)