# can i change my battery with other mAh batteries

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j5

My phone is ikon 787.its battery was recently damaged so i decided to change its battery. The original battery is 2600 mAh . I likes to change it with a 4100 mAh battery.Is it have any demerits. Do it have any problem on changing the battery with other specs.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145480/interchanging-battery-with-a-higher-capacity-battery

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can because all have the same cell voltage.
But it is not feasible as 4100 mAh battery will be of larger size and it will not fit in the phone with 2600 mAh.

If it can hold a larger battery then manufacture would have done this already.